Make hover box different colour from point
I visualise the participants of an event. I colour the points based on a number called "Engagement":
ata = pd.read_csv("formatted_data.csv")

fig = px.scatter_mapbox(
    data,
    lat="Latitude",
    lon="Longitude",
    zoom=4,
    height=0,
    color="Engagement",
    mapbox_style="carto-positron",
    hover_data={
        "Latitude": False,
        "Longitude": False,
        "Engagement": False,
        "1st study": True,
    },
)

fig.update_layout(
    margin={"r": 0, "t": 0, "l": 0, "b": 0},
)

colour_map = {1: "#ff0000", 2: "#2a00ff", 3: "#1be43c"}

colours = [colour_map[val] for val in data["Engagement"]]

fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=6, color=colours))
fig.show()

This leads to nicely coloured points that stand out against the background. However, the "first study" text that appears when one hovers over the points is hard to read as it's white on a light-green background. How do I change the colour of the text?

See the docs for customizations for Hover Texts and Labels.

This is my sample CSV data:
Latitude,Longitude,Engagement,1st study
34.0522,-118.2437,1,Study A
36.1699,-115.1398,2,Study B
40.7128,-74.0060,3,Study C
41.8781,-87.6298,1,Study D
29.7604,-95.3698,2,Study E
39.7392,-104.9903,3,Study F
34.0522,-118.2437,1,Study G
32.7157,-117.1611,2,Study H
37.7749,-122.4194,3,Study I



Using hovertemplate direct HTML manipulation
fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate='<b style="color: white;">%{customdata[0]}</b>',
    customdata=data[["1st study"]].values
)



Using hoverlabel dictionary
fig.update_layout(
    hoverlabel=dict(
        bgcolor="white",
        font_size=16,
        font_family="Lato"
    )
)


